# php statement for multiple users not working

Tags: php

I am helping in some PHP design for a friends text game and have come to a stump.

I have scheduled a cron job to call the following page / following code, which is working correctly

```
<?php require("connect.php"); ?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, name, health FROM users";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
$id = htmlspecialchars($row->id);
$name = htmlspecialchars($row->name);
$health = htmlspecialchars($row->health);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE living='1' AND ownerid='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
$OwnerName = htmlspecialchars($row->ownername);
$OwnerID = htmlspecialchars($row->ownerid);
$RaidPropBonus = htmlspecialchars($row->raidperc);
$RaidPropMoney = htmlspecialchars($row->raidcash);
$PropertyLvl = htmlspecialchars($row->proplvl);
$Living = htmlspecialchars($row->living);

    if($PropertyLvl == '5' && $Living == '1'){

        if($health < '100'){

            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET health=$health + '1' WHERE id='$id'")
            or die(mysql_error());

        } else { }

    } else { }
}
}
?>
```

Although this only works for ONE user only. I cannot understand why this is. Any other logged in / out accounts that have met the criteria have been ignored. I can maybe only think I am missing a loop? As the ID that is being met first is number 1 and it has stopped there?

Anybody advice at all maybe?

**UPDATE** - It seems correct I need to get a loop in there, but am so far failing to get this loop working correct. No matter where I seem to amend / add a loop it does not help. Please may somebody suggest anything?

**UPDATE2** - As requested, updated with the new version of loop

Comment: Try putting it in a loop.

Comment: There is no loop in your code

Comment: still using mysql_* this is deprecated, try using mysqli_* and prepared statements. also to add, you need a for loop to loop through each user where the condition meets your set criteria

Comment: Ah thanks. Missed this one, I have been going through and amending to mysqli today. I am used to VBA with my loops etc. How does this transfer over to PHP?

Comment: You need `while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {`

Comment: Thanks. Just need to figure out now where it goes. PHP is not a first language for me & so far I still cannot get this working.

Comment: as @Styphon says a *while* is enough. so you got there 2 queries, for each result of them you must add a loop. and AFAIC understand, the first while should have everything after line 5 (the first `mysql_fetch_object`) and the second would start after line 13 also till the end (the second  `mysql_fetch_object`)

Comment: @XicoXperto thank you for the reply. I have tried my double loop, but am still doing something quite obviously wrong as when I add the loop it stops working totally

Comment: @Zoltan can you update the question with the loop result you have done?

Comment: @XicoXperto I have now updated the main part with what loop I have tried to add

Comment: @Zoltan **Notice** that you're using the same variable names for both loops, which will be overwritten in the next, such as `$query`, `$row`, `$sql`... take a look at my answer, and see the variable names are more specific so that there are no overwrite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91531/discussion-between-xicoxperto-and-zoltan).

Answer (score 0):

For what I've understood, the loops should be made on the `mysql_fetch_object` that will get the each row from the query.

Take a look at the snippet

```
<?php 
require("connect.php"); 

// here prepare the $userQuery (the one that fetches all users)

// then the first loop that will read each usew row
// AFAICT this should afect all script
while($userRow = mysql_fetch_object($userQuery)) 
{

  // prepare data fetched from the $userQuery

  // prepare the $propertyQuery (the one that fetches all properties of the user)

  // then the second loop to read all user property rows
  // and this will afect the updates
  while($propertyRow = mysql_fetch_object($propertyQuery))
  {

    // prepare data fetched from $propertyQuery

    // add logic here

  }
}
?>
```

Also @Matthew Carpenter had a valid point, that `mysql_*` is deprecated, you should consider in using `mysqli_*`, or in my opinion take a look at [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Simple_Select_Statements)